# SeekBar not updating Android

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a `SeekBar` in my `ListView` Item. And a song for each item. When song is played I want `SeekBar` to update and or control `MediaPlayer` progres with `SeekBar`.
So far I have made it only to control, by dragging thumb to set  `MediaPlayer` progress. The problem is, I can't get it to update SeekBar Thumb position.

This is my code:

```
    Ids holder;
    private final Utils utils = new Utils();
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    long totalDuration;
    long currentPosition;
```

...

```
holder.seekbar.setMax(100);
        holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeProgressBar);
                int fullDuration = Item.mp.getDuration();
                int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(
                        seekBar.getProgress(), fullDuration);
                Item.mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
                updateProgressBar();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeProgressBar);

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {

            }
        });

        holder.seekbar.setFocusable(true);
        holder.seekbar.setEnabled(true);
        holder.seekbar.setTag(position);
```

...
playing file

```
Item.mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,
                        Integer.valueOf(this.songPos[songPosInt]).intValue());
                Item.mp.start();
                holder.seekbar.setProgress(0);
                updateProgressBar();
```

and finaly code to update SeekBar

```
public void updateProgressBar() {
        handler.postDelayed(updateTimeProgressBar, 1000);

    }

    private final Runnable updateTimeProgressBar = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Item.isPlaying == true && pausedSamePos == false) {
                currentPosition = Item.mp.getCurrentPosition();
                totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                int currentTime = (utils.getProgressPercentage(totalDuration,
                        currentPosition));
                holder.seekbar.setProgress(currentTime);
                Log.i("CALLED", "SHOULD BE UPDATED " + currentPosition
                        + "of total" + totalDuration);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

            }
        }
    };
```

Utils is a simple helper class to convert MS to SEC
I have also tried with

```
int totalDuration=mp.getDuration() /1000;
holder.seekbar.setMax(totalduration);
..
int currentPosition=mp.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
holder.seekbar.setProgress(currentPosition);
```

Seekbar

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="5.0dip"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_line"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_duration_sb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
        android:text="00:05"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#8C000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in my ListView View

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_frame2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_duration"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:text="00:05"
                    android:textColor="#8C000000"
                    android:textSize="14.0sp" />

               <include layout="@layout/play_item" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `handler.postDelayed(updateTimeProgressBar, 1000);` only executed once after 1000ms, so the progress bar will be updated once. Why don't create a `Timer` which runs every second to update the progress bar?

Comment: Um actually that  is working, I thought it didn't work, that it was called only once so I added Log and its working as intended, updating seekbar progress every 1 sec. But seekbar is not moving, nothing is happening

Comment: Also, `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` ran once. You might create this `handler` to be ran every second.

Comment: But it is running every second, I tested it again and instead of calling handler I called  `updateProgressBar` method, created loop. Still nothing.

Comment: Can u post the whole code of Activity and Adapter? (Related to the progressBar and Media playback)

Comment: I am facing issue with SeekBar can you please help me... here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692981/android-music-seekbar-is-not-working-idle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, wrong `SeekBar` was updating. So just add `SeekBar` listener and `runnable` inside `clickListener` and it'll work. Also extend base adapter and get item id.

Answer (score 2):

This is my implementation and it's working for me:

Somewhere in your code add this (once per song):

```
_seekBar.setProgress(0);
    _seekBar.setMax(_mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
```

And then update the seekbar using this code:

```
private Runnable _updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (_hasStopped) {
            return;
        }

        updateSeekbarView();
    }
};

private synchronized void updateSeekbarView() {
    if (_hasStopped) {
        reset();
        return;
    }

    if (_mediaPlayer == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (!_mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        stop();
        return;
    }

    long totalDuration = _mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    long currentDuration = _mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    _txtMax.setText("" + AudioUtils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
    _txtCurrent.setText("" + AudioUtils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
    _seekBar.setProgress((int) (currentDuration / 1000));
    _handler.postDelayed(_updateRunnable, 1000);
}
```

and the `AudioUtils.milliSecondsToTimer()` implementation in case you wanted to show the timer as text next to your seekbar:

```
public static String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
    String finalTimerString = "";
    String secondsString = "";

    // Convert total duration into time
    int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
    int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
    // Add hours if there
    if (hours > 0) {
        finalTimerString = hours + ":";
    }

    // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
    if (seconds < 10) {
        secondsString = "0" + seconds;
    } else {
        secondsString = "" + seconds;
    }

    finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;

    // return timer string
    return finalTimerString;
}
```

Comment: It's not working, the `updateSeekbarView` method is being called but `SeekBar` is not updating.

Comment: Can you paste the layout that contains the seekbar?

Comment: Layout pasted. I didn't include all items because its pretty big. If it's necessary for I'll paste whole layout

Comment: @SlimC. And if you remove these two, does it work? `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_line"` and `android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb"`. There may be something wrong with the drawables you use.

Answer (score 1):

In this case i think the holder reference gets dumped or changed to another view.

You can solve this by initializing the Runnable in the getView method like this:

```
View getView(){
...
updateTimeProgressBar = new Runnable() {
        Ids holderCopy = holder;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Item.isPlaying == true && pausedSamePos == false) {
                currentPosition = Item.mp.getCurrentPosition();
                totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                int currentTime = (utils.getProgressPercentage(totalDuration,
                        currentPosition));
                holderCopy.seekbar.setProgress(currentTime);
                Log.i("CALLED", "SHOULD BE UPDATED " + currentPosition
                        + "of total" + totalDuration);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

            }
        }
    };
}
```

But i really need to know how you play your song to be able to further help u...

Comment: Yeah I thought so too, and tried by updating SeekBar inside GetView method and it didn't work. After that I added log on OnProgressChanged method inside seekbar listener, and progress is changing but thumb position is not updating.So, could mean that wrong seekbar is updating? As for the rest of the code, I don't have it on this PC I will try to post it tomorrow if not, then Monday. But the Play Method is posted above.